# "Unreachable code detected" warning, does it affect my program?

Tags: loops, methods

I am getting errors saying "unreachable code detected". I am making a tic tac toe game and the errors show up when Im checking for the winner, which happens in the method names status and is called everytime a move is made. The program seems to be working normally so is this error serious or is it more of a warning? Thanks in advance.

```
    //Returns who the winner is (X, O, C for cats game), and ' ' for no winner yet
    public bool Status()
    {
        //check X horizontal win states
        if (board[0, 0] == 'X' && board[1, 0] == 'X' && board[2, 0] == 'X')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\\\\\\\\\\X is the Winner!//////////");
            return true;
            Reset();
        }
        else if (board[0, 1] == 'X' && board[1, 1] == 'X' && board[2, 1] == 'X')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\\\\\\\\\\X is the Winner!//////////");
            return true;
            Reset();
        }
        else if (board[0, 2] == 'X' && board[1, 2] == 'X' && board[2, 2] == 'X')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\\\\\\\\\\X is the Winner!//////////");
            return true;
            Reset();
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            return false;
        }
```

My guess is that because I put Reset(); after the return its not affecting whats being returned hence the error. does Reset() even do anything?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in assuming that your `Reset()` method is the reason for the unreachable code warning you are getting. Anything after a `return` statement is essentially `unreachable` because your method is being returned to its calling method and anything after it will not be run.

Answer (score 0):

Unreachable code is code that code before it does not allow to be executed.

> does Reset() even do anything?

We don't know, it's *your* program. But if you mean whether it is called then no, it is not.